# What's the theory behind this puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, theory, combinatorics

[image]

I recently came across the above puzzle game. The objective is to form a large triangle in such a way that the shapes and colors of the parts of the figures on neighboring triangles match.

One way to solve this problem is to apply an exhaustive search and to test every possible combination (roughly 7.1e9). I wrote a simple script to solve it ([github](https://github.com/enpe/the_magic_triangle)).

Since this puzzle is quite old, brute-forcing this problem may not have been feasible back then. So, what's a more efficient way (algorithm/mathematical theory) to solve this?

Comment: This question could/should reside at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to the [Edge-matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge-matching_puzzle) problem (with some regular polygons), which is of course **np-complete** (and there are more negative results i assume about approximations). This means, that there exists puzzles which are very hard to solve (at least if P != NP).

One interesting side-note: there is a very popular (commercial) edge-matching puzzle called [Eternity II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternity_II_puzzle) which had a prize value of two million dollars. It's still unsoved to my knowledge.

This problem resulted in many attempts and blog-writings, which should offer you much about solving these kind of problems.

Failed (in terms of: did not solve the full-size E2 puzzle; but other hard ones) approaches, which should work much better than exhaustive-search (without heuristics) are:

- SAT-solving (in my opinion most powerful *complete* approach)
- Constraint-programming
- Common Metaheuristics (a lot of potential when tuned to some problem-statistics)

Some interesting resources:

- Complexity-theory: `Demaine, Erik D., and Martin L. Demaine. "Jigsaw puzzles, edge matching, and polyomino packing: Connections and complexity." Graphs and Combinatorics 23.1 (2007): 195-208.`
- General hardness analysis (practical): `Ansótegui, Carlos, et al. "How Hard is a Commercial Puzzle: the Eternity II Challenge." CCIA. 2008.`
- SAT-solving approach: `Heule, Marijn JH. "Solving edge-matching problems with satisfiability solvers." SAT (2009): 69-82.`
- Edge-matching as benchmarks (because of hardness): `Ansótegui, Carlos, et al. "Edge matching puzzles as hard sat/csp benchmarks." International Conference on Principles and Practice of Constraint Programming. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2008.`

Comment: Edge matching was the keyword I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: No, this is _a restriction of_ the Edge-matching problem, which does show NP-completeness for nils's problem. ​ (Similarly, [2-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability) is a restriction of [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), which is NP-complete, but 2-SAT is in [NL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_(complexity)), which is a subset of P.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Did you check the first paper mentioned above? It's a signed edge-machting problem like figure 1, but using equilateral triangles instead of squares (which is also handled by the proofs).

Answer (score 0):

One common approach to solving this sort of problem is with **backtracking**.

You choose a starting place, put down one of the tiles and then try to find matches for it in the neighboring places.  When you get stuck, you back up one, and try an alternative there.

Eventually you have tried every possibility, without bothering with a huge number of dead ends.  Once you get stuck, there is no point in filling in the rest in any way, because you'll still be stuck at that one point.

More recently, Knuth has applied his **Dancing Links** algorithm to problems of this nature, with even greater efficiencies gained thereby.

For a problem the size of your example, with just 9 pieces and two "colors", all solutions would be found in a matter of seconds at the most.